# Count operation on Parquet Files using Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parquet

I have two sets of same data in Parquet format in HDFS.
One set is sorted on `col1` and another set is unsorted. The sorted_table is around 127 GB and the unsorted_table is around 117GB.
The size is no concern here.

I ran following two queries using Spark SQL:

```
select col1, count(*) from sorted_table where col1 = someInt group by col1

select col1, count(*) from unsorted_table where col1 = someInt group by col1
```

I analyzed these queries on spark UI, I found that the query on sorted_table reads only 127 MB of data and query on unsorted_table reads 35 GB data to figure out the count.

So my questions are:

1. How does Spark figure out the count by reading less data?
2. Why does the job on sorted_table read fewer data compared to the job on
   unsorted_table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parquet files are are stored in chunks called row groups.  Each row group can have some associated metadata for each field/column, including number of rows, minimum value, and maximum value.  Since your data is sorted, Spark can complete skip large chunks over your data based on these ranges.

Using `parquet_reader`, here's an excerpt from a Parquet file of mine:

```
 Column 2
 , values: 35957, null values: 0, distinct values: 0
   max: 17305, min: 17305
   compression: SNAPPY, encodings: RLE PLAIN 
   uncompressed size: 143866, compressed size: 6800
```

It's a `DATE` field, and all the values are the same, hence the same max and min.  But if I'm looking for a specific date range, Spark can use this to decide whether the actual data is worth examining.

There's more info about row groups here: https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/
But I don't see `min` and `max` listed ... that may be implementation specific.